# How to make, the elements in an array in a for loop call a function once

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```
stock=["AAPL","ADSK","AKAM","AMZN","CSCO","EA","INTU","NFLX","NVDA","QCOM", "MSFT","IBM"]   

for stocks in stock:
        test(stocks)
```

I want each stock to call the function once in each run,but all the stocks are being passed as arguments, and the results are coming for all stocks.
I even tried

```
for stocks in stock:
        test()
```

same results. Can it be possible to call the function in such a way, that it runs once for each stock,and then iterate.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the function" ? Your "stocks" are strings, what function should they be calling?

Comment: There are around 300 lines of code in the function test.

Comment: @MemberInspection You don't have to post the code for `test` but your question is not clear.

Comment: @MemberInspection I didn't ask you for the code of the function `test`, I asked you what you mean by having stocks "call" the function `test`. What you said typically means `stock.test()`, but since your stocks are plain strings, that won't work.

Comment: so it basically calls a number of other functions, and manipulates results as such,